Google Drive Desktop wasn't moving file, it's moved the file to trash then reuploading when moved by robocopy
So, I'm applying this 3-2-1 backup rule.

Folder form ssd-sync is synced to vhd-sync through robocopy, here is the argument command.
robocopy D:\ssd-sync E:\vhd-sync /LOG+:D:\ssd-sync\robocopy-autosync\ssd-to-vhd-robocopy-log.txt /V /DST /COPYALL /E /MIR /XO /XC /FFT ^
/SECFIX /TIMFIX ^
/W:1 /R:2 ^
/NP /NFL /NDL ^
/XF *tmp* *temp* *robocopy-log* ^
/XD *tmp* *temp* ^
/XF *.pyc *.exe *.log *.debug .idea *.sublime* *.dll *.o Thumbs.db .DS_Store *.bak *.old thumbs.db *.cache *.msi *.exe *.dmg *.obj *.class *.~* *.thumbnail *.thumb ^
/XD .venv node_modules .pio .git .vscode .idea *.sublime* *.dll *.o Thumbs.db .DS_Store *.bak *.old thumbs.db *.cache *.msi *.exe *.dmg *.obj *.class *.~* *.thumbnail *.thumb *build* *test* *tests* *logs* *output* *cache* *cached* *temporary* *thumbnails* *thumbs* *dependencies* *libs* *lib*  *.sublime*

And here is the sample log:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 11 May 2024 16:43:38
   Source : D:\ssd-sync\
     Dest : E:\vhd-sync\

    Files : *.*
        
Exc Files : .idea
        Thumbs.db
        .DS_Store
        thumbs.db
        *tmp*
        *temp*
        *robocopy-log*
        *.pyc
        *.exe
        *.log
        *.debug
        *.sublime*
        *.dll
        *.o
        *.bak
        *.old
        *.cache
        *.msi
        *.exe
        *.dmg
        *.obj
        *.class
        *.~*
        *.thumbnail
        *.thumb
        
 Exc Dirs : .venv
        node_modules
        .pio
        .git
        .vscode
        .idea
        Thumbs.db
        .DS_Store
        thumbs.db
        *tmp*
        *temp*
        *.sublime*
        *.dll
        *.o
        *.bak
        *.old
        *.cache
        *.msi
        *.exe
        *.dmg
        *.obj
        *.class
        *.~*
        *.thumbnail
        *.thumb
        *build*
        *test*
        *tests*
        *logs*
        *output*
        *cache*
        *cached*
        *temporary*
        *thumbnails*
        *thumbs*
        *dependencies*
        *libs*
        *lib*
        *.sublime*
        
  Options : *.* /FFT /DST /V /NDL /NFL /S /E /COPYALL /SECFIX /TIMFIX /PURGE /MIR /NP /XO /XC /R:2 /W:1 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      *EXTRA File         121089    E:\vhd-sync\Untitled.png
      *EXTRA File         105075    E:\vhd-sync\Untitled2.png
      *EXTRA File          43651    E:\vhd-sync\Untitled3.png

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :       513         1       512         0         0         1
   Files :      4560         3      4557         0         0         3
   Bytes :   6.292 g   263.4 k   6.292 g         0         0   263.4 k
   Times :   0:00:01   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:01


   Speed :             642.416 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :              36,759 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : 11 May 2024 16:43:39


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 11 May 2024 16:48:38
   Source : D:\ssd-sync\
     Dest : E:\vhd-sync\

    Files : *.*
        
Exc Files : .idea
        Thumbs.db
        .DS_Store
        thumbs.db
        *tmp*
        *temp*
        *robocopy-log*
        *.pyc
        *.exe
        *.log
        *.debug
        *.sublime*
        *.dll
        *.o
        *.bak
        *.old
        *.cache
        *.msi
        *.exe
        *.dmg
        *.obj
        *.class
        *.~*
        *.thumbnail
        *.thumb
        
 Exc Dirs : .venv
        node_modules
        .pio
        .git
        .vscode
        .idea
        Thumbs.db
        .DS_Store
        thumbs.db
        *tmp*
        *temp*
        *.sublime*
        *.dll
        *.o
        *.bak
        *.old
        *.cache
        *.msi
        *.exe
        *.dmg
        *.obj
        *.class
        *.~*
        *.thumbnail
        *.thumb
        *build*
        *test*
        *tests*
        *logs*
        *output*
        *cache*
        *cached*
        *temporary*
        *thumbnails*
        *thumbs*
        *dependencies*
        *libs*
        *lib*
        *.sublime*
        
  Options : *.* /FFT /DST /V /NDL /NFL /S /E /COPYALL /SECFIX /TIMFIX /PURGE /MIR /NP /XO /XC /R:2 /W:1 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    *EXTRA Dir        -1    E:\vhd-sync\Doksli\
      *EXTRA File          43651    E:\vhd-sync\Doksli\DISK-ALLOCATION.png
      *EXTRA File         105075    E:\vhd-sync\Doksli\GD.png
      *EXTRA File         121089    E:\vhd-sync\Doksli\SSD-VHD-HDD.png
      *EXTRA File         52.0 m    E:\vhd-sync\BERKAS_KULIAH\SBMPTN\Semester4\Sistem Operasi\alpine-virt-3.15.0-x86_64.iso

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :       513         1       512         0         0         2
   Files :      4560         4      4556         0         0         4
   Bytes :   6.292 g   52.25 m   6.241 g         0         0   52.25 m
   Times :   0:00:01   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:01


   Speed :           98.553.537 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :             5639,279 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : 11 May 2024 16:48:39


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 11 May 2024 16:53:38
   Source : D:\ssd-sync\
     Dest : E:\vhd-sync\

    Files : *.*
        
Exc Files : .idea
        Thumbs.db
        .DS_Store
        thumbs.db
        *tmp*
        *temp*
        *robocopy-log*
        *.pyc
        *.exe
        *.log
        *.debug
        *.sublime*
        *.dll
        *.o
        *.bak
        *.old
        *.cache
        *.msi
        *.exe
        *.dmg
        *.obj
        *.class
        *.~*
        *.thumbnail
        *.thumb
        
 Exc Dirs : .venv
        node_modules
        .pio
        .git
        .vscode
        .idea
        Thumbs.db
        .DS_Store
        thumbs.db
        *tmp*
        *temp*
        *.sublime*
        *.dll
        *.o
        *.bak
        *.old
        *.cache
        *.msi
        *.exe
        *.dmg
        *.obj
        *.class
        *.~*
        *.thumbnail
        *.thumb
        *build*
        *test*
        *tests*
        *logs*
        *output*
        *cache*
        *cached*
        *temporary*
        *thumbnails*
        *thumbs*
        *dependencies*
        *libs*
        *lib*
        *.sublime*
        
  Options : *.* /FFT /DST /V /NDL /NFL /S /E /COPYALL /SECFIX /TIMFIX /PURGE /MIR /NP /XO /XC /R:2 /W:1 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      *EXTRA File          2.1 m    E:\vhd-sync\BERKAS_KULIAH\SBMPTN\Semester4\Laporan6_09011282025077.pdf

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :       513         0       513         0         0         1
   Files :      4560         5      4555         0         0         1
   Bytes :   6.292 g   54.45 m   6.239 g         0         0    2.19 m
   Times :   0:00:05   0:00:01                       0:00:00   0:00:03


   Speed :           32.910.882 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :             1883,176 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : 11 May 2024 16:53:43


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : 11 May 2024 16:58:38
   Source : D:\ssd-sync\
     Dest : E:\vhd-sync\

    Files : *.*
        
Exc Files : .idea
        Thumbs.db
        .DS_Store
        thumbs.db
        *tmp*
        *temp*
        *robocopy-log*
        *.pyc
        *.exe
        *.log
        *.debug
        *.sublime*
        *.dll
        *.o
        *.bak
        *.old
        *.cache
        *.msi
        *.exe
        *.dmg
        *.obj
        *.class
        *.~*
        *.thumbnail
        *.thumb
        
 Exc Dirs : .venv
        node_modules
        .pio
        .git
        .vscode
        .idea
        Thumbs.db
        .DS_Store
        thumbs.db
        *tmp*
        *temp*
        *.sublime*
        *.dll
        *.o
        *.bak
        *.old
        *.cache
        *.msi
        *.exe
        *.dmg
        *.obj
        *.class
        *.~*
        *.thumbnail
        *.thumb
        *build*
        *test*
        *tests*
        *logs*
        *output*
        *cache*
        *cached*
        *temporary*
        *thumbnails*
        *thumbs*
        *dependencies*
        *libs*
        *lib*
        *.sublime*
        
  Options : *.* /FFT /DST /V /NDL /NFL /S /E /COPYALL /SECFIX /TIMFIX /PURGE /MIR /NP /XO /XC /R:2 /W:1 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :       513         0       513         0         0         1
   Files :      4560         1      4559         0         0         0
   Bytes :   6.292 g    2.19 m   6.290 g         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:01   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:01


   Speed :           4.761.601 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :             272,461 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : 11 May 2024 16:58:39

Here is my GD sync preference:

So, the problem is, once I move a file, for example ssd-sync/folderA/bigfile.iso to ssd-sync/folderB/bigfile.iso. Robocopy perform well to sync vhd-sync, it will do same vhd-sync/folderA/bigfile.iso to vhd-sync/folderB/bigfile.iso. But in Google Drive app, it's considered that action as deleting file and creating new file therefore it's moving the trash of vhd-sync/folderA/bigfile.iso then uploading vhd-sync/folderB/bigfile.iso.
Unlike if I do manually copy paste in explorer from vhd-sync/folderA/bigfile.iso to vhd-sync/folderB/bigfile.iso, the Google Drive desktop app know, it's just moving action. So the metadata that should updated is just path location.
I might be wrong in robocopy arguments.

Solved by using SyncToy instead of robocopy, any actions that SyncToy performed is recognized by google drive such as renaming file, moving file, etc.

Post that as the answer, not just a comment, so that it can help others experiencing similar/the same issue.

Solved by using SyncToy instead of robocopy, any actions that SyncToy performed is recognized by google drive such as renaming file, moving file, etc.
